# App Store Connect modify an already sent for review version

Tags: ios, updates, release, app-store-connect

I have a new update version for my app in the state "Waiting for review" and I was asking me if can modify certain settings of that version without stop or cancel the process.

The case is that I would like to change the "Version Release" section from "Manually release this version" to "Automatically release this version".
See picture

Is it possible?

[image: Version Release]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can change it. Just select what you want and click save.